# Finding xpath siblings after declaring a variable with find_elements

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I start by trying to find all menu items on a site by selecting them with a .find_elements_by_xpath. This works fine

(The buttons are either text or an image).

Then I want to loop through each of these elements and return either the text between the tags or the src of the image of a span tag which preceeds the tag inbetween which there is text.

Returning the text works fine but I am unable to return the src. I am having trouble building an xpath which roots from the current iteration of the loop. What I am left with is either an 'unable to locate' or I return the first menu image over and over again.

Here is the code I currently have running (note I am unable to give out the URL to the site):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(...)
menu = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@onmouseover]')
for menu_part in menu:
try:
    if len(menu_part.text) < 2:
        menu_button = menu_part.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/span[@class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText"]/preceding-sibling::span/img').get_attribute('src')
    else:
        menu_button = menu_part.text
    print menu_button
except Exception as e:
    print e
    pass
```

I am unsure if the syntax is completely correct/ if I can use the currently iterated element as the 'root' of my find_element function (menu_part.find_element_by_xpath)
Also, there is no way to further specify the tags with attributes because all menu items have identical attributes.
Lastly, the following code returns the first image in the menu.

```
menu_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//span[@class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText"]/preceding-sibling::span/img').get_attribute('src')
```

Therfore, I am relatively confident the code following "span[@class... " works fine, the issue is the preceding code.

I am hopeful that there is a simple solution and that I made a mistake while writing the xpath, but I am completely out of ideas at the moment...

EDIT:

here is the basic html structure I am dealing with

```
<td class="ThemeOfficeMainItem" onmouseover="ItemMouseOverOpenSub ()">
    <span class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderLeft">
        <img src="img1.png"></span>
    <span class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText">TEXT</span>
    <span class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderRight">&nbsp;</span>
</td>
<td class="ThemeOfficeMainItem" onmouseover="ItemMouseOverOpenSub ()">
    <span class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderLeft">
        <img src="img2.png"></span>
    <span class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText"></span>
    <span class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderRight">&nbsp;</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you add the html for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for `span` starting from previously defined parent element  `menu_part`, then you should use

```
./span[@class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText"]/preceding-sibling::span/img
```

Note the dot at the beginning of `XPath` that points to current (`menu_part`) element

**Update**

As for the logic of your code, try below:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
menu = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@onmouseover]')
for menu_part in menu:
    text_span = menu_part.find_element_by_xpath('./span[@class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText"]')
    if not text_span.text:
        menu_button = menu_part.find_element_by_xpath('./span[@class="ThemeOfficeMainFolderText"]/preceding-sibling::span/img').get_attribute('src')
    else:
        menu_button = text_span.text
    print menu_button
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but it simply returns "unable to locate"

Comment: Ok, so I am very confused, but if I use menu[x] (so it would go as follows: menu[x].find_element...) instead of menu_part then it works. I suppose I could use enumerate to get the elements location in the list as x, but I don't understand why I can't simply use menu_part

Comment: Still have the same problem... to be honest, I am even more confused now. If I pass on an explicit location in the menu list, then it works (i.e. menu[1].find_element... -> returns the second image in the list). But, as soon as I pass on a variable that changes such as x which increases by one per loop iteration, I recieve an error that the content could not be located. How is this possible?

Comment: Actually I have no idea as my code works as expected with `HTML` sample you've provided... Your  sample `HTML` might differs from real `HTML` or you've incorrectly implemented my code

Comment: I feel bad for having used up so much of your time! I removed some of my code when creating my answer and I just realized that it was skipping precisely those iterations where it would have found the images. The two parts of code were not really related so I didn't think to check before. Anyways, thanks for the help!